# How to check characters at a certain position in a string .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

In my project the customer have a card and a 7 letter particular security code is in it. I want to ask 3 letters from that security code by position.

```
eg. card security code is  **57GHY58**
```

I want to ask **what is the Character at  2,4 and 7  position in your security code**?

```
answer is  **7H8**
```

How to generate that question with random postion and **how to check it** ?

Comment: Well, do you know how to generate random numbers? (Look at the Random class.) Do you know how to extract a character given the index? (Look at the string indexer, or Substring.)

Comment: Good logical question !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static int[] GetThreeRandomNumbers()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    Random r = new Random();
    while (list.Count < 3)
    {
        int num = r.Next(1, 7);
        if (!list.Contains(num))
        {
            list.Add(num);
        }
    }
    list.Sort();
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a string with indices 0-6. You need to pick 3 indices from that range randomly. The `Random` class will help you with this, have a look at its method [`Random.Next(int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it will return you a random number from the specified range. Then the only other thing you have to do is skip the indices you have already used.